# Why touchesMoved method will not be triggered in iphone sometimes?

Tags: iphone, multi-touch

I have enabled multiply touch. but when i put one finger on the screen at first and put another finger on the screen after that. Then i moved one finger of the two and keep another one not moving, the touchesMoved method will not be trigger sometimes? Is there any one have any idea about that?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Multiple touch means "two fingers placed at a time" and not one after another.

Comment: yes, at last, there's two fingers on the screen, there's just a little period of time between they place on the screen. but when they are all on the screen , i move one of the two fingers, the touchesMoved method will not be called sometimes.

Comment: delay between both the touches might be more than the max delay apple is observing between each touch. have to analyze more